# How to get rid of [VM] line in Chrome console?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, developer-tools

**Now I can see about VM line in my chrome developer tools like this.**

[image]

There are some solution that I found,
such as make gray 'pause button'

[image]

however, it was already gray in my developer-tool
and it was also not worked for me.

How can I get rid of that VM messages in my console?

Thanks for read my problem.

Answer (score 3):

With the right mouse click on a VM:xxx link select "Reveal in Sources panel", and study the code that causes those console messages.

In my case, I found there this line - `original Method(...format WithStyles(args, 'color: ${color}'));`, and other lines there revealed that it was referring to React Devtools Extention. So in its *"Components" console tab => Settings gear icon => Debugging tab =>* I checked on the "Hide logs during second render in strict mode" option.

It helped me, but it can be some other extension in your case. Study the source code of a message first.

Answer (score 1):

Open Chrome console, than select All Levels (it may appear like Default, if so, click it.) See in the list if Info is checked. If it is checked, close it. It helped me to get rid of it, hope it will help you to get rid of [VM] line in Chrome console too.

Check the image below:

[image]

Comment: Sorry about late check. 
And thanks for the answer!!